# Using requiresExplicitBindings on parent Guice module results in "not explicitly bound" error for checked provider

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, guava, guice

I am trying to use a Guice checked provider to create a particularly expensive object. The idea is to lazily load it so the creation won't impact the application startup time and handle exceptions if it cannot be created. I followed [Guice wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders) and bound the provider in its own specific module. I also bound another class which injects the provider as a dependency in the same module. This module was then installed in another root module and I was able to create the injector successfully from it. The problem occurs when I try to add `binder().requiresExplicitBindings()` to the root module to prevent Guice from creating just in time bindings. The error is:

```
Explicit bindings are required and <class> is not explicitly bound.
```

The class that injects the provider as a dependency is created successfully when I remove `binder().requiresExplicitBindings()`. I am assuming that Guice does not create JIT bindings for the provider(?).

So the question is, can I use checked providers and make the module require explicit binding at the same time? Is it a limitation of Guice or am I implementing it incorrectly? Given below is an example which can be run using JUnit and reproduces the issue.

*Java version: 1.8*

*Guice version: 4.1.0*

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Scopes;
import com.google.inject.throwingproviders.CheckedProvider;
import com.google.inject.throwingproviders.ThrowingProviderBinder;

class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException() {
        super();
    }
}

interface MyProvider<T> extends CheckedProvider<T> {
    @Override
    public T get() throws MyException;
}

class MyStringProvider implements MyProvider<String> {
    @Override
    public String get() throws MyException {
        return "myString";
    }
}

class MyStringUser {
    @Inject
    public MyStringUser(final MyProvider< String > myStringProvider) {}
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder())
            .bind(MyProvider.class, String.class).to(MyStringProvider.class)
            .in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

        bind( MyStringUser.class );
    }
}

class MyMainModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        binder().requireExplicitBindings();

        install( new MyModule() );
    }
}

public class GuiceTest {
    @Test
    public void test_givenMyMainModule_whenCreatingInjector_thenReturnNonNullValue() throws Exception {
        assertThat( Guice.createInjector( new MyMainModule() ), is( notNullValue() ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, report it here: https://github.com/google/guice/issues